# RavenDB : Can we query a not yet saved document?

Tags: ravendb

I'm asking my question here because I didn't find any answer in the RavenDB's online documentation.
However, my question is quite simple : can we query a non saved document in the same session that the document has been stored ?

```
using( var session = store.OpenSession() )
{
    session.Store( new SampleObject() { Name = "My name is sample" } );

    var sample = (from o in session.Query<SampleObject>()
                where o.Name = "My name is sample").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

sample will be null ?
Do I have to use "Customize" method on the query to load non stale data ?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new document wasn't transmitted to the database yet, you have to call `session.SaveChanges()` before querying. Additionally you have to customize your query to wait for the index to catch the new documents, but you've spotted that already.